# Matching continuous function through moments

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(h_n)$ be a sequence of continuous functions $h_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ such that $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (\int_0^1 h_n(x) x^i dx)^2 \to 0, \;\; (n \to \infty).$$ Does it then follow that $\int_0^1 h_n(x)^2 dx \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 1):

No, the functions could have a peak near $0$, or rather double $\pm$ peak to have zero integral. Like this: 
$$
h_n(x) = n\chi_{[1/n,2/n]} - n\chi_{[0,1/n]}
$$
Then the $0$th moment vanishes, and for $i\ge 1$,
$$
\int_0^1 h_n(x)x^i = n\frac{2^{i+1}-2}{(i+1)n^{i+1}} \le \frac{2^{i+1}}{(i+1)n^{i}} 
$$
One can see that the sum of squares is $O(n^{-2})$.

Yet, $\|h_n\|_{L^2}\to\infty$.